# TypeScript lists imported interface and types in generated JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a module A which exports classes, types and interfaces:

```
export class Event {
    // empty
}

export interface EventHandler {
    handle(event: Event): void
}

export type EventCallback = (event: Event) => void
```

I can use this in another module B:

```
import {
    EventCallback,
    EventHandler,
    Event
} from "./ts_interface_bug"

let x: EventCallback = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
}

class MyHandler implements EventHandler {
    handle(event: Event): void {
    console.log(event)
    }
}
```

but the compiler keeps the types when generating JavaScript (`B.js`):

```
import { EventCallback, EventHandler, Event } from "./ts_interface_bug.js";
let x = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
};
class MyHandler {
    handle(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

This is wrong - no code is generated for types and interfaces as you can see in `A.js`:

```
export class Event {
}
```

Is this a bug or can I somehow configure the TypeScript compiler to omit types and interfaces?

TypeScript 3.5.3

`tsconfig-build.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "ES2016",
    "lib": [
        "dom", "ES2016"
    ],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        {
            "transform": "@zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension/output/index.js"
        }
    ],
},
```

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ttsc --build tsconfig-build.json",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension": "^1.0.1",
  "ttypescript": "^1.5.7",
  "typescript": "^3.5.3"
}
```

Comment: That has to be a bug

Comment: I'm not immediately seeing a report in [the issues list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), probably worth reporting there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Same as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29263?

Comment: Are you sure it's TS doing the compilation and not babel ? I can't reproduce this issue in an empty project with just the tsconfig and files you provided

Comment: @AaronDigulla nope, that specifically only occurs if the usage is in a type in a computed property name ..

Comment: I would expect babel to get this wrong since it does not do multi-file analysts so has no way of knowing what is imported is  are just types. Although since these imports will not be used anywhere in JS code they will probably get optimized out by whatever bundler/minifier you will eventually use so I would not worry about it too much.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not using babel but `"ttypescript": "^1.5.7"`, so I can use the transformation `"@zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension": "^1.0.1",`. Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not using a bundler/minifier since I'm lazy loading (or rather you can add plugins to my app at runtime, so there is no way to build a bundle beforehand).

Comment: @AaronDigulla perhaps .. don't have any experience with ttypescript but my understanding of it is that it's just the same ts compiler with minimal changes. Depends how they do compilation though, I remember the compiler API having a function that does work similar to the way babel does compilation, but this is kind of at the edges of my expertise, maybe tag this with ttypescript ? or file an issue on ttypescript github since this is not reproducible with vanila TS

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I disabled ttsc and compiled with tsc and that fixed the issue. I think it's a bug in ttsc and `typescript-transformer-append-js-extension`.

Answer (score 1):

The example above works when using `tsc --build tsconfig.json`. There must be something wrong either in ttypescript or the `typescript-transformer-append-js-extension` plugin (which works in import statements to fix https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577).

I've opened a bug: https://github.com/Zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension/issues/3

**UPDATE** Apparently, the bug was that I need to run the transformer *last*. This fixes it:

```
"plugins": [
    {
        "transform": "@zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension/output/index.js",
        "after": true
    }
],
```